# undefined reference to gst_x_overlay_get_type - Error when compiling Gstreamer basic tutorial 5

Tags: gstreamer

when i try to compile gstreamer basic tutorial 5 source, I get the following error:
/tmp/cczEt1RC.o: In function `realize_cb':
basic-tutorial-5.c:(.text+0x50): undefined reference to`gst_x_overlay_get_type'
basic-tutorial-5.c:(.text+0x70): undefined reference to `gst_x_overlay_set_window_handle'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Command I used to compile is:
gcc basic-tutorial-5.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0` `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-0.10` -o 5basic

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 3):

gstreamer sdk website had the gcc command but was hidden
gcc basic-tutorial-5.c -o basic-tutorial-5 `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-interfaces-0.10 gtk+-2.0 gstreamer-0.10`